# fatal error: stdlib.h No such file or directory #include_next <stdlib.h>

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, cmake, makefile

I am working on windows 10 computer, in VSCode with a GCC compiler. I am using cmake to create make files and I compile the make files using make. I have to do `cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles"` in order to do make after. When I `make` I get this error [This is the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9nY5.png)

Can someone give me a simple explanation and an easy solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we discourage **images** which represent a **text**. Please, paste the error message into the question post in textual form. You could format inserted as a code. See also [ask].

Comment: Can you show us your Makefile? **include_directories** or **target_include_directories** with **SYSTEM** argument can sometimes mess up stuff.

Other things you maybe could try is:
1. Execute make VERBOSE=1 to get the failing line.
2. I would play around with the flags (especially the include flags in this case) to find a workaround. Make sure to add add -v to summon verbose mode as it shows lots and lots of useful information.